# How do I cat/show a file from HEAD without checking it out?

Tags: git

Consider this example repo:

```
git init .
echo a > a
git add a
git commit -m 'commit a'
echo edited >> a
```

The file a in HEAD has contents:

```
a
```

while the file a in the working tree has contents:

```
a 
edited
```

How do I `cat` the contents from HEAD without touching the `a` file in the working tree?

Comment: @torek Thank you.